# How to transfer n elements from an array to new array

Tags: java

User input size of array. User size for array * 2 is array.
For that size program made random elements.
User input how much elements want to transfer to array2.
User input how much elements want to transfer to array3.
My program(I think so) work fine but, when I input that I want to move 3 elements from first array in second array, program print me first 3 elements and next elements are just zero.

Example:
User input size of array 5
Array is user size * 2
arr  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
User input that he want 3 elements to transfer in new array, arr2.
arr2 [1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

And same for third array.
So, my question is, how I can fix that zeros, so I just want to have three elements from first array.

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
User input that he want 3 elements to transfer in new array, arr2.
arr2 = [1,2,3]

Here is my code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.out.print("Input size of array: ");
    int arraySize = input.nextInt();

    int arr[] = new int[arraySize * 2]; //User size * 2

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(100);//Random elements for array size
    }
    System.out.println("Array before sort: " + Arrays.toString(arr));//
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.println("Array after sort: " + Arrays.toString(arr));

    System.out.print("Input first n elements that you want to move in second array ");
    int nElementsForSecondArray = input.nextInt();

    //First n elements that user input and creating new array2
    int arr2[] = new int[arraySize * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < nElementsForSecondArray; i++) {
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Second array: " + Arrays.toString(arr2));//Print array2 with n elements from first array

    System.out.print("Input first n elements that you want to move in third array ");
    int nElementsForThirdArray = input.nextInt();

    //First n elements that user input and craeting new array3
    int arr3[] = new int[arraySize * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < nElementsForThirdArray; i++) {
        arr3[i] = arr[i];
    }
    System.out.println("Third array: " + Arrays.toString(arr3));//Print array3 with n elements from first array
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you set the size for the second and third array to the same size as the original array if you only want to have `nElementsForSecondArray` in it?

Comment: I change it now but when I run program it works, but at the end program send my ArrayIndexOutOfBounds!

Edit: Now work fine everything, I just delete arraycopy! Can you help me how I can now connect array2 and array3 in one array? Without collections and etc